# PRAW: can you receive data from two seperate keyword lists in the same message?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a reddit bot that receives keywords from a subreddit and then sends me a notification on Slack.

The current code for sending me the notification is

```
for kw in keywords:
                if kw.lower() in comment.body.lower():  # case insensitive check
                    already_alerted_submissions.append(comment.submission.id)
                    msg = '[Keyword *{0}* detected](http://www.reddit.com{1})'.format(
                        kw, comment.permalink)
                    slack_data = {'text': msg, 'mrkdwn': True}
```

So it is currently getting a list of keywords from

```
keywords = ['camera', 'nikon', 'canon', 'campus']  # case insensitive
```

I was wondering if it was possible to have two separate keyword lists in the file such as the following

```
keywords = ['camera', 'nikon', 'canon', 'campus']  # case insensitive
keywords_color = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black']  # case insensitive
```

And if the word "camera" was detected in a thread, it would post a message just like it does currently.

But if in the same comment, it detected a keyword from both 
keywords AND and keywords_color

It could post the same message in slack but with another line saying something similar to "Color was detected"

So in the examples above the message in slack would look like the following.

```
1. [Keyword *camera* detected]
(http://www.reddit.com/r/camera/comments/9yg8mt/goodcameras
I just got a great CAMERA today, it is awesome
```

Or if it detected both "keywords" and "keywords_color" it would look like the following

```
2. 1. [Keyword *camera* detected]
(http://www.reddit.com/r/camera/comments/9yg8mt/goodcameras
I just got a great CAMERA today, it is a RED one and its awesome
**Colour was detected**
```

Would this be possible? any help would be appreciated!

The full scrip for the file is here:

```
def main():

    alerted_comments = get_list_from_pickle('alerted_comments.pickle')

    try:

        for comment in comment_stream:
            if comment.id in alerted_comments:
                continue

            if comment.author:  # if comment author hasn't deleted
                if comment.author.name in ignore_users:
                    continue

            for kw in keywords:
                if kw.lower() in comment.body.lower():  # case insensitive check
                    alerted_comments.append(comment.id)

                    while len(alerted_comments) > 100:
                        del alerted_comments[0]

                    with open('alerted_comments.pickle', 'wb') as fp:
                        pickle.dump(alerted_comments, fp)

            for kw in keywords:
                if kw.lower() in comment.body.lower():  # case insensitive check
                    alerted_comments.append(comment.submission.id)
                    msg = '[Keyword *{0}* detected](http://www.reddit.com{1})'.format(
                        kw, comment.permalink)
                    slack_data = {'text': msg, 'mrkdwn': True}

                    response = requests.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/BE72P09A9/xxxxxxxxx78',
                                             data=json.dumps(slack_data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
                    if response.status_code != 200:
                        raise ValueError('Request to slack returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s' % (
                            response.status_code, response.text))

    except Exception as e:
        print('There was an error: ' + str(e))
        sleep(60)  # wait for 60 seconds before restarting
        main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: We were chatting about this in the Python IRC channel (#python on FreeNode), but I'm commenting here for the record. @Vestipial, I'm going to rewrite this as you asked. Also, what do you want it to do if multiple keywords match?

Comment: Hi mate, thank you so much, I really do appreciate it!

So currently, if it detects a word from the keyword list, it sends a notification with the following: (On 3 separate lines)

1.Keyword *camera* Detected
2.Then the permalink
3. Then the comment the keyword was found in.

So what I was hoping for, if it found a keyword from both keyword lists. Instead of doing the above, it would do the following:

1.Keyword *camera* Detected
2.Then the permalink
3. Then the comment the keyword was found in.
4. 'Colour was detected'

Or whatever text I change that 4th line to.

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, what if multiple keywords are found, e.g' camera' and 'nikon'?

Comment: Ahh, I get it.
If multiple keywords are found, it can just do as it does currently and post it twice. 
Unless you have a better idea

Comment: Its not a massive issue, since the keywords mostly will not be as generic as that.

Comment: Well, for now I'll just leave it at posting once, with the first keyword encountered, and leave that for later.

Comment: Ok sounds great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but here you go:

```
import json
import time

import requests


class SlackError(Exception):
    # This isn't quite how I would handle this, so for now it's
    # just a hint of more to learn.
    pass


MSG_TEMPLATE = """[Keyword *{keyword}* detected]
(https://www.reddit.com{permalink})
{comment_body}"""

SLACK_WEBHOOK = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/BE72P09A9/xxxxxxxxx78'


def main(*, save_path):
    keywords = ...
    color_keywords = ...
    ignore_users = ...

    comment_stream = ...

    with open(save_path, 'r') as fp:
        alerted_comments = json.load(fp)

    for comment in comment_stream:
        if comment.id in alerted_comments:
            continue

        if comment.author:  # if comment author hasn't deleted
            if comment.author.name in ignore_users:
                continue

        if any(kw.lower() in comment.body.lower() for kw in keywords):
            found_kws = [kw for kw in keywords if kw.lower() in comment.body.lower()]

            msg = MSG_TEMPLATE.format(
                keyword=found_kws[0],
                permalink=permalink,
                comment_body=comment.body
            )

            if any(kw.lower() in comment.body.lower() for kw in color_keywords):
                msg += "\nColour was detected"

            slack_data = {'text': msg, 'mrkdwn': True}

            response = requests.post(
                SLACK_WEBHOOK,
                data=json.dumps(slack_data),
                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            )

            if response.status_code == 200:
                # Moving this here so you don't miss a comment
                # because of an error. It does mean other errors
                # could potentially cause a repeat message. There
                # are ways to handle that.

                alerted_comments.append(comment.id)

                if len(alerted_comments) > 100:
                    alerted_comments = alerted_comments[-100:]

                with open(save_path, 'w') as fp:
                    json.dump(alerted_comments, fp)
            else:
                # You'll probably want to be more discerning than "not 200",
                # but that's fine for now.
                raise SlackError(
                    'Request to Slack returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s' % (
                        response.status_code, response.text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            main(save_path='alerted_comments.json')
        except Exception as e:
            print('There was an error: {}'.format(str(e)))
            time.sleep(60)  # wait for 60 seconds before restarting
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing that, wow, you rewrote the whole thing. thats much more than you needed to do! but thank you.

So i  guess to add my reddit praw login details I would import praw, then add the login details.. the script I got it updated from was here. 
https://pastebin.com/d8akemm6


So would I just add those top details as well the keywords and subreddit details?
I totally missed adding that in my SO post I just noticed.
I did add them and tried to run the script, but initially got a There was an error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'alerted_comments.json' error

Comment: @Vestipial That's the gist of it; I don't know PRAW offhand. As for that error, the code is assuming `alerted_comments.json` already exists. You can fix that, or for now, you can just create it containing just `[]`; an empty list of comments.

Comment: Ahh ok, cool. I have done that. now I am getting 
There was an error: Extra data: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Comment: raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


I am guessing I need to do something else apart from "import praw" and those reddit details, ill have to have a sift through, maybe I need to rename some things to match your code

Comment: Did you copy the semi-colon with the brackets? It's `[]` not `[];`.

Comment: Ahh sorry, misread that!
Ok have updated that haha. sorry, I didn't notice it was not a part of the code.
So now I get the followng" 
`There was an error: 'ellipsis' object is not iterable`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 99, in <module>
    main(save_path='alerted_comments.json')
  File "bot.py", line 48, in main
    for comment in comment_stream:
TypeError: 'ellipsis' object is not iterable`

Comment: That was just a placeholder. It wasn't defined in your code, so I just put `...` for you to fill in.

Comment: Ohh ok. the original code was set out like this (the code I had working)
https://pastebin.com/E95kgekh

So what would I do with your code
`keywords = ...
    color_keywords = ...
    ignore_users = ...

    comment_stream = ...`

Sorry to be such a pain :(

Comment: All good! I got it to work, thanks so much!

I just moved mysubreddit,  keywords, keyword_colour, and content_stream details and replaced yours.
then I got a permalink not defined error, so I changed permalink to comment.permalink
Awesome man!, now to play around with formatting it.. thanks again! what a legend!

Comment: Oh, yea, `comment.permalink`. I almost made it. :)

Comment: Haha, you did awesome!
Next question (its ok, I will try to figure it out on my own, you have done more than enough!) 
Is it possible to turn this into a Slack Bot?
I have activated a slack bot API, and created a webhook through there as well and changed the webhook on the script.
It does indeed send the message through the new Slackbot which is awesome. but I was hoping that I could do a couple of things now.

1. When "Colour is detected" - have it send a @here command to the channel so everyone gets a notification
2. Format the style so its a nicer UI (this is obviously cosmetic only)

Comment: Enjoy :). Since this helped, I'd appreciate you upvoting and accepting the answer.

Comment: Oh, crap, yes, of course I will haha. ill do it now.
Quick question, If I want to add slack data, such as formatting, adding icons, creating that colored line down the left hand side etc. I would add those into the actual script? or create a seperate json and put the data into that?

Comment: I accepted it but am unable to upvote until I have 15 reputation, as soon as I get it, I will come back and upvote!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the actual script versus separate JSON. I presume you would just add it to the `slack_data` dict, but I don't know the format; I'm sure the Slack developer docs will say.